# Dyntopo creating spikes or stretched sculpt result on mesh

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

When I try to sculpt with dyntopo on a sword it creates really weird results while it works just fine on other meshes. Any idea what causes this?

[image: spikes]

Comment: Increase the detail size from 12 to 75 and change from relative detail to constant detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick test and it might be also that your object has other scale than 1,1,1.

The solution is to have your object selected and in the object mode press **Ctrl+A** and select **Scale** from the **Apply** menu.

Here I have more than 15 for the Z scale of a cube and the dyntopo sculpt result with the same settings as yours is quite stretched, like yours.

[image]

After applying the scale to 1,1,1, dyntopo behaves way nicer, again with the same dyntopo settings as yours:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much! This was the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

We might need more info here.
If you are using a texture, make sure your brush size and dyntopo settings make that you create enough geometry in order to make the texture's details correctly.
Also, check the strength of the stroke, too much strength with a texture is rarely good.

Otherwise, that might be an issue from your original mesh's geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally turned the brush setting under *Direction* for my smooth brush from *Smooth* to *Enhance* and this caused it to stretch the vertices into different directions instead of averaging them out. Try turning the back